# I have lost the prompt on Terminal on my Mac; unable to get commands to work

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I was trying to launch a few Java applications using the terminal. The command that I was instructed to launch it with (I was following a guide) was the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$( dirname "$0" )"
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar
```

It worked the first time, which was a test run, so I hide the terminal window to work on some other things. But when I opened the terminal window back up again, I noticed that I had lost my `root@pcname:~$` prompt that usually starts with my terminal opening up.

I have tried to kill anything running in the background but nothing seems to work. When I enter a command it just moves me to the next line without executing anything. Please help and answer in simple terms, as I am not incredibly Terminal-savvy. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your command is still running. Type <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> to get your prompt back, followed by `bg` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to let Minecraft continue in the background.

If you want to avoid similar issues in the future, call either the shell script itself or at least java with `&` at the end to put it into the background directly:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar &
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be help to see the guide you have been following. It seems like you started a bash script.

If you want to simply regain root rights use `sudo su`.

You can also use `whoami` to verify your username you are currently logged in on the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

type

```
su
```

and enter the root password, or better, use `sudo` in front of `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar`

Comment: And how exactly does this solve the problem described in the question?